# Is there an equvalent for perror in the kernel?

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, kernel

What would perror() be in the kernel? I can't tell what the error codes are from the error values ,i.e -22 alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel just uses negated errno codes as a convention.  So look in `asm-generic/errno-base.h` or `asm-generic/errno.h` and find...

```
#define EINVAL          22      /* Invalid argument */
```

This can happen if you pass `NULL` to a function that doesn't accept `NULL`, for example.  It depends on the function.

Comment: the question was about using `perror()`, not about the meaning of the error codes.  So this is not a good answer.

Comment: @user3629249: This question not actually about using `perror`, but it's about how to interpret error codes in the kernel. The `perror` function is only available in userspace, it's not available in the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old but I came across it and I found a workaround which is a little more satisfying than the accepted answer.

It's true there's no actual perror but errors can be printed in a nicer way (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html#error-pointers). All we need to do is to supply the error pointer or convert it with the `ERR_PTR` function if we have a numeric value (basically just a cast) and we are settled.

One could then print the error directly or create their own perror as in the example:

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

#define MYPERROR(str, err) printk(str ": %pe\n", ERR_PTR(error))

static int __init mymodule_init(void) {
    int error = -22;
    printk("The error is %pe\n", ERR_PTR(error));
    MYPERROR("Failure", error);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit mymodule_exit(void) {
}

module_init(mymodule_init);
module_exit(mymodule_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```